# Screenshot saving issue on Moto G running Lollipop -- unable to clear the notification

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, motorola-moto-g, screenshots

My phone has been saving a screenshot for three days now. I can't clear the notification so I'm wondering what  should I do? I'd like to keep it if I can for some reasons. If I can't keep it how do I clear the notification?

I'm tired of restarting my phone but that didn't do anything. And I'm using Moto G running Lollipop

Comment: Is the image correctly saved? If the reboot did not solve that issue, try force stopping the associated app that causes that notification.

Comment: So I used a task killer and stopped everything "unnecessary". The notification is gone and in my gallery is a black image. Oh well. Thanks, otherwise I would have had that notification for years to come.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove the notification, force stop the app. Long hold the notification, go to app info and choose force stop.

Comment: Yep - thanks I stopped it but lost the image. All good now though.

Comment: @user117852 Glad I helped you! Could you accept the answer for the help of others? Thanks!

Comment: There you go all good